# How to insert a new user programmatically to my forum?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xamarin, mybb

I have a xamarin.forms mobile app, and i have [mybb forum](http://www.mybb.com).

Is it possible that when a user is creating a new account in the app, user can login to the website with the same credential?

what is the query for doing such a thing?

insert into mybb_users values(............); < what is the MUST INSERT fields

I will only use use email+Password+name  (Other fields I will make them null or default value)

Example:

```
INSERT INTO mybb_users (username, password,email) 
VALUES 
('username','password','abc@abc.com');
```

Or should i insert other fields to null or  default value

authentication is already done inside the mobile app.

---

UPDATE:

I have insert a user into mybb_users tables successfully

but when i try to login using the username, i got error message saying user is not registered ??

How do i know what other needed tables i have to fill

---

Update 2:

This is the registration Page: [member.php](http://pastebin.com/pJPuiF9Q)

Comment: you have not need to pass all table fields in insert query just pass that you have need to insert data into table 
INSERT INTO mybb_users (`username`, `password`,`email`,`etc...`) 
VALUES 
('username','password','abc@abc.com','etc..');

Comment: @Divyesh, the problem if there are tables that depends on some fields of mybb_users table. foreign keys and such

Comment: You need to go to the MyBB community development forums and ask this. There's usually 3+ tables that need to be updated when registering a user. PhpBB for example has 3 base inserts, 6 config updates and a 4th insert if admin level auth.

Comment: I have asked there but no Answer. Mr @Brian If u know how to do it in PhpBB i will use PhpBB now. tell me where to look

Comment: PhpBB has all the info you need in the [3.0.x] MOD Writers Discussion forum. Full integration and registration. Just a few simple searches and you should find what you need. I've done this with phpbb since the first release. It's quite easy actually.

Comment: Using MySQL Only without php? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to define all of the columns as long as you are fine with them being null.

See [MySQL Insert references](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) for more info.

To answer your second question, you will need to look at the table and the login form itself to see what fields they need. Insert values into those columns.

Comment: The problem if there are tables that depends on some fields of mybb_users table. like for example foreign keys. how to know?

Comment: Thank @sub6resourcesm, Unfortunately i don't understand php.I tried getting something out of it but i could't

Comment: Maybe add the login code to the question. It will help us know what to do. If possible, give us a list of the columns in the table as well.

Comment: I can't add login code cuz it is a pop up window. so I don't know where to find it? http://i.imgur.com/WsOHMDc.png I attached registration file. Anything else u need tell me. Thank u for ur time @sub6resourcesm